# Influence of gate resistors and capacitors on driving gate of mosfet

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, semiconductors, gate-driving

Good Day,

I wannted to ask in a typical gate driving circut of a Mosfet, we always have Rgoff, Rgon,RGS and CGS as shown in below screenschot. What is the purpose of these components in driving the gate of mosfet and how these components influence the switching of mosfet.
Thanks[image]

Comment: C1 never appears if you want to drive the MOSFET at a decent switching speed and, it's unlikely that D1's placement is correct if you want to turn off the MOSFET quickly (ditto R1's value). In short, what was the motivation for your schematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Driving a MOSFET is all about the current available to charge/discharge the input capacitance \$C_{iss}\$ of the considered transistor. The total amount of charges for this operation is designated as \$Q_G\$ in the data-sheet and usually expressed in nC (nanocoulombs).

Assume a MOSFET like the [IRF530](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/irf530.pdf) requiring a 26 nC (max) total gate-charge to bring its gate from 0 to 10 V with a 14-A current when its drain is biased at 80 V (specifications in the data-sheet). If you want to turn it on in 100 ns, then you will need to bias the gate-source terminals with a 10-V source capable of delivering an instantaneous peak current of \$i_g=\frac{26n}{100n}=260\$ mA. If you want to turn it on faster, then you make sure more current is available from the driving source. On the opposite, if you want to slow it down, you insert a resistance to limit the peak.

1. The network made of \$R_1\$ in parallel with \$R_2\$ and \$D_1\$ provides an asymmetrical drive resistance to the gate. When the source at your VGS node goes high, the current sees two parallel paths via \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ since \$D_1\$ will conduct. On the opposite, when the VGS node goes to 0 V, the only discharge path is via \$R_1\$ as \$D_1\$ blocks. You thus purposely want to have different switching times for turning on and off this transistor. This is quite unusual actually (unless this an error in your sketch?) as, most of the time, you want to slow the turn on to avoid hard-switching losses via high di/dt but want a fast turn off to limit losses. You would, in this case, reverse diode \$D_1\$ to achieve this characteristic.
2. A resistance in series with the gate is recommended to damp the \$LC\$ network made of PCB parasitics and the MOSFET input capacitance. This ringing can be deleterious and sometimes affects the MOSFET lifetime if too high in amplitude. A damping resistor helps curing this. Please note that these damping elements must be located very closely to the MOSFET connections, not far away at the driver output side.
3. Resistance \$R_3\$ is there to make sure the gate is always tied to source in case wrong solder joints leave \$D_1\$ and \$R_1\$ unconnected. It could happen during production and, when it is the case, you don't want the whole thing to blow up with a gate left floating. 47 kOhms is a good value and is enough to keep the gate low. I've often seen 10k or even less and it uselessly consumes drive current which is "expensive" in bootstrapped circuits.
4. Capacitor \$C_1\$ is not often seen in high-speed circuits but can be present depending on the applications. For instance, if a very slow turn-on is required then this capacitor could be there but you usually avoid adding capacitance because you pay it with extra drive current.

Comment: Thank You so much for this detailed explanation.

Comment: With pleasure : ) You can validate the answer if this is what you were expecting. Thank you.